# where can i download libCurl

Tags: curl, httprequest, libcurl

the official website of curl is "https://curl.haxx.se"

and the download page is "https://curl.haxx.se/download/"

but in download page there is no "libCurl" for win32 generic or win64 generic
there is only curl binary release

i need a c or c++ library to send http request, i think the best one is libCurl but i don't know where should i download the library because there is only binary for download

should i compile library from source code?
is there  something like "curl.lib" to download ?

......................................................

at the end i should say sorry about this simple question i'm new to c++ libraries...

Comment: Maybe try asking at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is Yes, you have to compile the libraries by yourself. 
It is very good documented on their website: [Install curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)

There is also an part about building curl for windows with different compilers. I hope this answer will help you and good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

`https://curl.haxx.se/download.html`

Or you can just clone the repo:

`https://github.com/curl/curl`

Be aware that if you download a lib (not recommended), it has to match your compiler, debug/runnable version and architecture(32/64bit) because c++ mangles function names.